# Android: How to obtain individual data usage counters?

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, wifi, counter

The challenge at hand is how to obtain accurate data counters for each Network Interface.
The class TrafficStats offer some help with:

```
TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() /* Similar for TX */
TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() /* Similar for TX */
```

From this one can calculate the traffic on the mobile interface.
However I see several posts claiming that:

- WIFI usage = Total - Mobil;

That cannot be correct since Total includes -all- of the Network interfaces (i.e. Bluetooth and USB as well as WIFI and Mobile). Thus the WIFI result can be very off its actual correct value using the above calculation.

Can anyone assist or offer assistance on how to accurately analyse each of the NetworkInterfaces?

Answer (score 0):

> That cannot be correct since Total includes -all- of the Network interfaces (i.e. Bluetooth and USB as well as WIFI and Mobile).

I am not completely certain how you have determined that Bluetooth and USB are included in `TrafficStats`.

> Can anyone assist or offer assistance on how to accurately analyse each of the NetworkInterfaces?

There is nothing in the Android SDK for anything but what you get from `TrafficStats`. You are welcome to [play around with trying to get the information from Linux](http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html), bearing in mind that this may not work on all devices.

Comment: From the Developer documentation I find the following definition of TrafficStats:
public static long getTotalRxPackets ()
Added in API level 8
Return number of packets received since device boot. Counts packets across all network interfaces, and always increases monotonically since device boot. Statistics are measured at the network layer, so they include both TCP and UDP usage.

"... across all networks .."
Listing Networks on my device (HTC ONE X) I get a list including:
> BLUETOOTH_TETHER
> USBNET
.. Both Bluetooth and USB are among the Network Interfaces.

Comment: @user2802170: You assume accurate documentation, which unfortunately is not a valid assumption. I would recommend that you actually test it, using Bluetooth (and, in a separate test, USB), and confirm the impacts on `TrafficStats`.

Comment: Yes I agree the documentation is at times terrible...
In the name of laziness .. has anyone else tested the facts claimed in this post; i.e. USB and Bluetooth traffic is included in the TrafficStats counter?

Comment: @user2802170: That's probably better off asked as a separate StackOverflow question.